# Polybase in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2016, polybase

Just wondering if Polybase functionality in SQL Server 2016 would allow to search non-relational database. We use TRIM for our document management system. Would upgrading to SQL Server 2016 allow us to then search the TRIM documents?

Thanks

Comment: Polybase currently supports querying from Hadoop and Azure Blob Storage (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143171.aspx). Unless TRIM is based on one of these technologies, you will not be able to use Polybase to query TRIM.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2016 Polybase engine allows you to join relational data with non-relational data. You can bring in non-relational data from Hadoop clusters to SQL Server and vice versa. Hence I suppose you should be able to search the TRIM documents.